# How to check a div is exists or not?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an “exists” function for jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

```
 <div class="XXX">
  <div class="created">
  </div>
</div>
```

div `class="created"` automatically generated by JavaScript using append function jQuery for some validation i need to check whether div is generated or not how can i do this.using jQuery.

something like `$('.xxx').html()==' '`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this like following:

```
$('div.XXX div.created').length
```

if the `div` is not create then `$('div.XXX div.created').length` will return 0.

```
if( $('div.XXX div.created').length > 0 ){
  // do something 
}
```

In jQuery, it has method **[`.size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size)** and implement like `$('div.XXX div.created').size()`, but `.length` is more reliable.

Answer (score 5):

you can use jQuery [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property which returns the number of selected elements:

```
if ($('.XXX div.created').length > 0) {

}
```